# How to calculate covariance matrix in nonlinear least squares

Tags: least-squares, optimization, covariance-matrix, nonlinear, hessian

I am fitting a nonlinear model to observations by using least squares to estimated the model parameters.

Theoretically, the covariance matrix of the parameters can be estimated by inverting the Hessian (of the objective function: RMS of residuals in my case) at the converged point (optimal solution).
However, the method seems numerically unstable at least in my case: the calculated covariance matrix depends strongly on the step sizes for the finite-difference approximation I use to numerically calculate the Hessian.

My model is too complex and the Hessian can be only numerically evaluated (by finite difference approximation of derivatives at the converged point or by approximation inherent in specific optimization algorithms).

Could you tell me any better method than simply inverting the numerically approximated Hessian?

Comment: are you familiar with bootstrapping?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes, may I apply the bootstrap sampling to the observation data to estimate the variance of parameter estimates? I am not sure whether it gives a good estimate of the variance.

Comment: asymptotically, the bootstrap distribution converges to the sampling distribution, so we can calculate just about whatever statistic we want from it.

Comment: Thank you. Is the bootstrap sampling often used to estimate covariance matrix?

Comment: this aint really my wheelhouse, unfortunately, but I do see some literature pop up simply searching "bootstrap covariance matrix" https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=bootstrap+covariance+matrix&btnG=&oq=bootstrap+covariance

Comment: I see. Thank you.